# What does "for as " mean separately in "for as you are as handsome as any of them"?

Tags: word-meaning, sentence-structure

> “I see no occasion for that. You and the girls may go, or you may send them by themselves, which perhaps will be still better, **for as** you are as handsome as any of them, Mr. Bingley may like you the best of the party.” ( Pride and Prejudice)

I don't understand why "for" and "as" are used together, what do they mean respectively?
It sounds like "for" means "because" though.

Comment: ...For (because), as you are as handsome as any of them, Mr. B. may like you the best... There are already a lot of commas in the sentence, but adding another might have made it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just confused. As you've mentioned 'for' means 'because'. And after that comes "as you are / as handsome as / many of them...". Just add a coma after 'for' and it will be clearer. It's just some punctuation error.